# Alpaca slider not working

Tags: slider, range, daterangepicker, alpacajs

I am trying to run alpaca slider but I am not able to use it in my project with property `slider= true` any idea how can I make it work using alpaca only. Is any specific version of alpaca needed for this to work?

I am using following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#field2").alpaca({
        "data": 18,
        "options": {
            "type": "integer",
            "label": "Snow Days:",
            "helper": "Number of Snow Days in January 2011",
            "slider": true
        },
        "schema": {
            "minimum": 1,
            "maximum": 31
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Stackoverflow.

There are two solution for this, your code is correct but to show the slider for your component you should add **jquery-ui** to your page. The second solution is to add the property `inputType` in the `options` object.

```
/..
"options": {
  "id": "test",
  "type": "integer",
  "label": "Snow Days:",
  "helper": "Number of Snow Days in January 2011",
  "inputType": "range", 
},
/..
```

Comment: Thanks for warm welcome and the solution. 
It worked for me. But according to slider changes the value change also should be shown in text view its not showing up. I tried with inputType in options object.

Comment: Please help me out, I am trying to solve this from so many days.

Comment: Yes I'll do my best, but can you send me a picture to see the final result you want ?

Comment: Yes, In this link http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/integer.html  please check exaple no 2. I want slider like that and value should display in textview. Somehow its not displaying in my project.

Comment: This might be because you haven't use jquery-ui, do you have errors in your browser console? I rewrite the code using only the slider option to true and it worked. here's a fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/ggtg7jsc/2/
Try adding Jquery-ui to your project if it isn't there.

Comment: I am using jquery-ui but still somehow its not showing slider. Cant get whats the issue.

Comment: the code in your question is that all the code you used? can you give me the versions of the libraries you used?

Comment: JQuery-UI:  1.11.4,
JQuery: 2.2.0, and yes the code is same which I am using.

Comment: I got the solution, problem was with version only. with 1.12.0 version its running fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there any way to add slider to date and time field in alpaca or jquery?

Comment: I never did somethig like this before, I'll digg on that on Monday and I will get back to you.

Comment: Have you got any solution

Comment: Hi, I saw that you opened another question, I tried to use this plugin http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/technicalDemo.html but I had some issues with jquery-ui, I think they use a custom one. I will continue the searching.

Comment: Thanks for reply vert3x..I am also trying hard. Please let me know whenever you get something working.

Comment: sorry for the late response, unfortunately I still haven't any solution for that plugin :/ I'll try to find another plugin or solution for this...maybe this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery UI version 1.12.1 and jquery version 1.12.4 
"inputType": "range" in options json is working for me. This should work for you.

```
$(function() {
$("#field2").alpaca({
    "data": 18,
    "options": {
        "inputType": "range",
        "label": "Snow Days:",
        "helper": "Number of Snow Days in January 2011",
        "slider": true
    },
    "schema": {
        "minimum": 1,
        "maximum": 31
    }
});
```

});